# Implementing Enumeration types in C++

Tags: c++, enums

So i am trying to create a class that is of enum type except that i have never used enum types before and im in the process of learning. I understand that enumeration type is basically `enum a(red, blue green);` where red would =0, blue =1 and green =2. But from there i dont quite understand how to further implement this enums class. If i have a header class such as

```
#ifndef COLOR_H
#define COLOR_H


class Color
{
    public:
        enum Color {red, blue, green};
};

#endif // COLOR_H
```

and then a cpp file which goes like this:

```
#include "Color.h"

enum Color::Color {red, blue, green}{
 //dont know how to implement in here
}
```

How would i implement the member function so that if the Color is passed 1 from main.cpp, then the member function will lets say print out blue?

Comment: `enum Color {red, green, blue};` is its own type definition. No need to wrap it in a class. Turning an enum into a string, however, isn't provided by C++ naturally. You have to use a workaround if you want to do that.

Comment: Well, enums are really just constant integers. What are you trying to achieve? What other feature do you expect?

If you want to call a specific function based on a enumeration constant, either do a specialized template (can only be called with compile-time constants), or a function taking the enumeration as a parameter, then include a switch table that selects the appropriate function to call.

Comment: Actually I think you're not allowed to use the same name for a class member than for a class.

Comment: In case you are coming from Java, C++ enums are more primitive than Java's. They aren't types for which you can create methods (although you can imitate this with free functions), and they absolutely don't have the ability to create easily overrides of class-enum methods for individual enum values, which is IMO an awesome Java feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for an "enum implementation" (whatever that means to you). You can simply have:

```
struct Color {
    enum ColorInternal {red, blue, green};
};
```

and access the enum values as `Color::red`, `Color::blue`, `Color::green` and the enum as `Color::ColorInternal`.

Alternatively you can simply use an `enum class`:

```
enum class Color {red, blue, green};
```

and access the values as `Color::red` and the class as `Color`.

Comment: Does this compile, with a member having the same name than the struct ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for implementation in a .cpp file - What is in the header is enough. Incidentally, you don't actually need a class to hold an enum. simply writing `enum Color {Red, Blue, Green};` is enough.

You can think of it as a cleaner way to write:

```
#define Red 0
#define Blue 1
#define Green 2
#define Color int
```

There are several fundamental differences but the point is that this too can be written in a .h file. Of course, you should never use the above example, it is horrible programming practice.

Comment: A better analog would be `typedef int Color; const Color Red = 0; const Color Blue = 1; const Color Green = 2;`. (Except that you can't take the address of an enum constant.)

Comment: I know, I wasn't certain what @ShadowViper had learned, and from my experience most people learn #define before typedef or const.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an other way way:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

enum ECOLOR { RED, BLUE, GREEN };

class Color
{
public:
    Color();
    ~Color();
    Color(ECOLOR);
};

Color::Color(ECOLOR color)
{
    switch (color)
    {
    case RED:
        Console::WriteLine(L"Hello Red\n");
        break;
    case BLUE:
        Console::WriteLine(L"Hello Blue\n");
        break;
    case GREEN:
        Console::WriteLine(L"Hello Green\n");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Color *blue = new Color(BLUE);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Aternative 1: simple enum type**

You could define in your header a simple enum type without a class:

```
enum ColorType { red, blue, green };  // Simple enum
```

You could overload common stream operations for example for printing the value, tailor made:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, ColorType color) {
    switch (color) {
    case red:
        std::cout << "red" << endl;  break;
    case blue:
        std::cout << "blue" << endl;  break;
    case green:
        std::cout << "green" << endl;  break;
    }
    return os;
}
```

In main(), you could then use it easily:

```
    ColorType val = red; 
    if (val==blue) 
        cout << "blue";
    cout << val;
```

I'd recommend this in most cases.

**Alternative 2: Complete color class**

However, you cannot enrich an enum of alternative one with a different semantic, for example to allow for adding colors (or even washing away color intensity at each copy) or other member functions.

For this enriched approach you'd need a class.  Here you'd need to change slightly your definition.  First, a **member cannot have the same name as the class itself** (otherwhise type definitions and constructors would be extreamly ambiguous !):

```
class Color
{
public:
    enum MyColor { red, blue, green };  // That's just a nested type
    Color(MyColor c = red);             // That's a constructor for the class, with a default value
    void print();                       
private: 
    MyColor color;                      // That's a value
};
```

You could then start to use this class:

```
Color cr = Color::MyColor::red;  // access to nested color type needs some extra typing
Color choice; 
choice = cr; 
choice.print();         // of course you'd need to define print() first
```

Then it's up to you to enrich this class.